# Chrome Incognito: Make Default Browser

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, private-browsing

I know that I can make Google Chrome start in incognito mode by adding "-incognito" in a shortcut. However, if I click on a link in Outlook or a word processor, for example, the link will still open in Chrome's normal mode.

How can I make Google Incognito my DEFAULT browser so that when clicking on links in another program, they open in Google Incognito automatically, not normal mode? I want Chrome Incognito to actually be my default browser without having to open it myself using the "-incognito" shortcut.

Comment: The same question for macos: https://superuser.com/questions/1358466/chrome-69-open-links-from-external-apps-in-front-incognito-window

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible using a registry edit. Start `Regedit.exe` and go to:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Shell\open\command

Double-click `(default)` and include the `-incognito` switch after `Chrome.exe`. For example, if the value data is set as:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"`

Change that to:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito "%1"`

That should do it.

(On a 64 bit system, if you installed the 32-bit version of Chrome, the path would look like
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito "%1"`)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, restarting your computer isn't necessary. Thank you w32sh, you're a genius.

Comment: YW..Glad to have helped!

Comment: This needs to be done everytime chrome updates itself, that’s the only thing that we need to keep in mind