# Chrome 69: Open Links from External Apps in Front Incognito Window?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, private-browsing

I usually have a regular and an incognito window open in Chrome. Usually (and on purpose), the frontmost window is the incognito one. Before Chrome 69, links from external apps (e.g. .webloc files in finder or links from Vienna RSS reader) opened in the frontmost window. Now, these links open in the background, non-incognito window.
Is there a way to get the old behavior back?
I'm running Chrome 69 on macOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 0):

From https://forums.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=27092&p=140440#p140440

You can solve this by opening the URL chrome://flags/#views-browser-windows in Chrome and switching to Disabled.

Unfortunately as of the December 7th release of Chrome, this no longer works. But if you have an older version, it will.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the issue in Chromium bug tracker with a discussion: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=757253

I've found the ChromeBuddy app: https://github.com/AndreyGr/ChromeBuddy?tab=readme-ov-file that addresses changed behaviour in Chrome 68. It is set as default browser and opens the links in Chrome's foremost window